# Requests to ASP.NET Core API get stuck in pending state

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I am working on ASP.NET Core MVC project and I have some JS code that calls my API endpoints to get some extra data.

So I am doing some AJAX requests. And while some are successful, others seem to be stuck in pending state (state from browser's devtools), please see attached picture:

[image]

You can see some XHR requests are successful (and I can hit breakpionts in those endpoints, debug, etc.).

And ones below are stuck in pending state ("oczekuje" is pending). I can't hit breakpoints in those endpoints, but I can hit and debug middleware, so it gets stuck somewhere in HTTP request pipeline I guess.

And I guess my question here is looking for any clues, as i am not sure where else I could look.

**EDIT**

To add more context, I am migrating from .NET Framework 4.5 and there it runs correctly. Here are the sizes of the requests:

[image]

Comment: Try to send a request to your endpoint with postman and see what happens. Afterwards debug a non-working request step by step in your code. Can also be that you are missing a return or something and the method simply never finishes

Comment: Are the files in pending huge files?

Comment: @Aaron compiler would not allow such situation.

Comment: @PrashanthBenny Please see my update.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn try to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example for us. It's just guessing at this point because we dont see any code. There needs to be something wrong with ur config / endpoints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I guessed, it was something internal to C# code, some recursion of some sort or dead lock.

So I followed MS documentation on how to [Debug a deadlock in .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/debug-deadlock?tabs=windows) :

- firstly installed tools `dotnet-dump` and `dotnet-trace` with `dotnet tool install` command
- then I run the app, run the command `dotnet-trace ps` to get process ID of the running app and then `dotnet-dump collect -p 8280` (with ID of found process)
- this will write dump to file - just run `dotnet-dump analyze path-to-file` to analyze the dump

This will enter interactive mode, where `clrstack -all` will output stacks of all threads.

As I analyzed, I noticed that `ServiceCollection` tried to resolve some circular dependency, as I have endless stack on one thread such as below:

[image]

So I narrowed the problem and found problematic dependency and fixed DI registration and usage.

That solved the issue.